# Add prefix to all values in a column in the most efficient way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with over 5M rows. I am concerned with just one column in this dataframe. Let's assume dataframe name to be `df` and the column in consideration to be `df['id']`. An example of the dataframe is shown below:

df['id'] :

```
    id
0   432000000
1   432000010
2   432000020
```

The column `df['id]` is stored as a *string*.

I want to add a prefix to all the rows of a particular column in this dataframe. Below is the code I use:

```
 for i in tqdm(range(0,len(df['id']))):
       df['id'][i]='ABC-1234-'+df['id'][i]
```

While the above code works, it shows 15 hours to complete. Is there a more efficient way to perform this task ?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide some sample data with the desired output. There are a number of ways to approach the problem, but especially with string operations, it may be highly dependent on the input data

Comment: `df['id'] = 'ABC-1234-' + df['id']`?

Comment: Or if the text needs to be replaced somewhere inbetween, you can also use `df['id'].map('ABC-1234-{}'.format)`. But I guess @QuangHoang's version is faster because it doesn't need a `map` call.

Comment: @QuangHoang's version works like a charm!